# Error when extension is deployed: "There is no data provider registered that can provide view data"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension:
https://github.com/crhistianramirez/jiraIssues

Which works just fine when I debug it locally but for some reason doesn't work when its deployed. My package.json has main set to ./out/src/extension and I can see the compiled javascript does indeed have a file in the expected location and it registers a data provider.

I would very much appreciate a nudge in the right direction or any suggestions on how to debug something like this that is deployed and doesn't appear to be reproducible locally.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything useful in the "Developer: Toggle Developer Tools" console? I just ran into this problem; the issue for me was that my extension wasn't being activated because I had some of my runtime `dependencies` listed in `devDependencies` by mistake. Even if your issue isn't the same, there should be some useful logging there.

Comment: Aha! That's very helpful. So I got  Error: Cannot find module 'request'. appreciate you very much

Comment: @TonyAllevato I find no error in `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`. In fact it is showing extension is activated. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am getting the error in debug mode as well.